# Delegate @State value to a child component

Tags: swift, swiftui

A Swift new guy here. Trying to understand SwiftUI.
I'm trying to create a "Field" component that wraps a Text and TextField. The idea is to have less code and have a control that can display the field title and its corresponding value.

I can't figure out how to assign the value of the model on my control.

This is my model:

```swift
import Foundation

class EmployeeModel {

    var FullName: String = "John Doe"
    var JobStartDate: String = ""
    var BornDate: String = ""
    var DepartmentId: Int = 0
    var DepartmentName: String = ""
    var isBossDepartment: Bool = false
    var JobPositionId: Int = 0
    var JobPositionName: String = ""
    var PersonalDocNumber: String = ""
    var Password: String = ""

    init() {
    }

}
```

In some part of the view...

```swift
struct EmployeeView : View {
    @State private var Employee = EmployeeModel()

    var body : some View {
        Field("Full Name", $Employee.FullName)
    }
}
```

This is my custom component that want to implement.

```swift
struct Field : View {
    private var caption: String = ""
    @State private var controlValue: String = ""

    init(caption: String, value: String) {
        self.caption = caption
        controlValue = value
    }

    var body : some View {
        VStack {
            Text(self.caption)
            TextField($controlValue)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I got a message of

'Binding' is not convertible to 'String' on my Field implementation of the EmployeeView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before going into the details of your problem, please be advised that by convention, types (classes, structs, enums, etc) should begin with a capital letter, while objects and values should start with a lower case (or underscore). By not following that convention, you make the code hard to read for others, as everyone is expecting it.

Now, on your code, there are several improvements:

1. `controlValue` must be declared as `@Binding`.
2. `@Binding` properties should not have an initial value, as they are supposed to be passed by the caller.
3. If you declare your properties non-private, you wouldn't need an initializer. Nothing wrong with that, but if you do use an initializer, there are multiple changes you need to perform (see the code below).
4. Your TextField is using a deprecated and discontinued initializer in beta 5.

```swift
struct EmployeeModel {

    var fullName: String = "John Doe"
    var jobStartDate: String = ""
    var bornDate: String = ""
    var departmentId: Int = 0
    var departmentName: String = ""
    var isBossDepartment: Bool = false
    var jobPositionId: Int = 0
    var jobPositionName: String = ""
    var personalDocNumber: String = ""
    var password: String = ""

    init() {
    }

}

struct EmployeeView : View {
    @State private var employee = EmployeeModel()

    var body : some View {
        Field(caption: "Full Name", value: $employee.fullName)
    }
}

struct Field : View {
    private var caption: String = ""
    @Binding private var controlValue: String

    init(caption: String, value: Binding<String>) {
        self.caption = caption
        self._controlValue = value
    }

    var body : some View {
        VStack {
            Text(self.caption)
            TextField("", text: $controlValue)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and advices, really I appreciate this. I will perform an update to the last version and keep deeper.

Comment: You're welcome. When you do upgrade to beta 5, `.roundedBorder` changed too. You'll need to update it to: `.textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())`.

Comment: Hi @kontiki I just came to confirm that your solution works like a charm.